# Osm2pgsql failed due to error when I try to import data into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, database, osm2pgsql, nominatim

I am using the following [link](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) to install openstreetmap server on my ubuntu 14.04 server. I have followed their tutorial line by line and installed most of the dependencies and everything. When I try to import the North America's map data into my PostgreSQL database it is throwing an error. I am using this command to load all the data

```
osm2pgsql --slim  -d gis -C 16000 --number-processes 1 /usr/local/share/maps/planet/north-america-latest.osm.pbf
```

but it is throwing an error as you see on image.

```
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Error: Connection to database failed: FATAL: role 'azureuser' does not exist.
```

[image]

`azureuser` is the username of my terminal and when configuring my `postgresSQL` database I created a user `'openstreet'` and database `'gis'`. If you open the link you can also see the command to import data under the section `Importing data into the database` but that is not working for me. Could anyone help me with this error? I am not able to move forward from here

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved this error:

The problem is still your `pg_hba.conf` file (/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf). This line:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

Should be

local   all             postgres                                trust
```

After altering this file, don't forget to restart your PostgreSQL server. If you're on Linux, that would be `sudo service PostgreSQL restart`.

Once you have done this you need to change the Osm2pgql command. In this command my database name is `gis` and username is `openstreet`.

```
osm2pgsql --slim -U openstreet -d gis -C 16000 --number-processes 1 /usr/local/share/maps/planet/north-america-latest.osm.pbf
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a pragmatic solution for a dev box, but I'd also recommend that you [read this page on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Backend_Security_Project_PostgreSQL_Hardening#pg_hba.conf_-_Client_Authentication) for info on postgres security. Also, read section 19.3.1 in the Postgres manual.